# xquery to check if the value is null then return null as string

Tags: xquery, informatica, informatica-cloud, application-integration, cloud-integration

I am new to XQuery. Please guide me to solve the issue below I want to return the `null` value as a string, if the below expression does not give any value.

Currently, the output doesn't show the 'name' field itself. I want to have a name with `null`. for eg-

```
if (IsNull(expression),null,expression)

$output.dataAccessResponse[1]/*:row/*:name/text()
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`fn:exists()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-exists) function to test whether or not there is a `text()` node.

```
exists($output.dataAccessResponse[1]/:row/:name/text())
```

You could also use the [`fn:boolean()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-boolean) function to test the effective boolean value of the node.

```
boolean($output.dataAccessResponse[1]/:row/:name/text())
```

If you wanted to test whether or not there was a significant value i.e. something other than whitespace, you can [`fn:normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-normalize-space) in a predicate, to ensure that only `text()` nodes that have meaningful text are selected, and then test `fn:exists()`.

```
exists($output.dataAccessResponse[1]/:row/:name/text()[normalize-space()])
```

XQuery doesn't have `null`, so if you are asking what to return to indicate `null`, then you would want to return an empty sequence `()` instead of `null`.

So, you could execute something like this:

```
let $name := $output.dataAccessResponse[1]/:row/:name/text()
return 
  if (fn:exists($name)) 
  then $name 
  else ()
```

But at that point, it's really the same as just attempting to select the `text()` with that XPath and it will either return the `text()` node or an empty sequence:

```
$output.dataAccessResponse[1]/:row/:name/text()
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response.but i am looking for if statement.te code should return the original value if exists else empty sequence ().Exists would return true/false.

Comment: okay, it wasn't quite clear what you were asking for. Just address the `text()` node with the XPath and it will either return the node, or an empty sequence. No need for if/else blocks at all.

Comment: Since name is null,i am getting  <MSG>THIS IS TEST MESG</MSG>
         <NEW_NUM>N</NEW_NUM> .however i am expecting the output as   <name/>
         <MSG>THIS IS TEST MESG</MSG>
         <NEW_NUM>N</NEW_NUM>

Comment: i have given the xpath to text already.$output.dataAccessResponse[1]/:row/:name/text()

Comment: If you want to copy the name element, then select the name element. It might be helpful if you showed more of the code for context and to see how this is being evaluated.